# Clean up Python function with too many if/else statements

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a working function with too many `if/else` statements (pylint). The code works but it's not good. I try to improve it but I have some tunnelvision. Can someone help me to improve the code?

So depending on a list of stacks, an environment (prod, nonprod or all) and a list of account IDs there can be filtered on which stacks need to be updated.

This is an example of a stack dict:

```
{'AccountId': '123456789101',  'StackName': 'test-nonprod'}
```

function:

```
def filter_stacks(stacks, environment, account_ids):
    """todo"""
    non_prod_regex = re.compile("(nonprod|non-prod)")

    stacks_to_update = []

    if non_prod_regex.match(environment) and account_ids:
        for stack in stacks:
            if (
                non_prod_regex.search(stack["StackName"])
                and stack["AccountId"] in account_ids
            ):
                stacks_to_update.append(stack)
    elif non_prod_regex.match(environment) and not account_ids:
        for stack in stacks:
            if non_prod_regex.search(stack["StackName"]):
                stacks_to_update.append(stack)
    elif re.compile("all").match(environment) and account_ids:
        for stack in stacks:
            if stack["AccountId"] in account_ids:
                stacks_to_update.append(stack)
    elif re.compile("all").match(environment) and not account_ids:
        stacks_to_update = stacks
    elif not non_prod_regex.match(environment) and account_ids:
        for stack in stacks:
            if (
                not non_prod_regex.search(stack["StackName"])
                and stack["AccountId"] in account_ids
            ):
                stacks_to_update.append(stack)
    elif not non_prod_regex.match(environment) and not account_ids:
        for stack in stacks:
            if not non_prod_regex.search(stack["StackName"]):
                stacks_to_update.append(stack)
    else:
        print("No match found.")

    return stacks_to_update
```

Comment: Looks like you have tried to optimize the code, putting loops in different branches. What do you want - readability or optimization? For readability, you probably should make a single loop over the if statement.

Comment: Also, regexes are the same every time the function is called. Make them static (i.e. global or attached to class object or something), not compile them every time.

Comment: Without some more context, a review will be difficult. I think that the whole "non-production" logic is a non-starter and is indicative of suboptimal design.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: @PavloSlavynskyy Whereas OP should follow your advice, strictly speaking _compile them every time_ is not what actually happens since there is a regex compilation cache.

Comment: @Reinderien thnx gone reading

Comment: don't have the time to write a full answer but a couple of suggestions. imo the top-level if-else should be something like: `if environment in ["nonprod", "non-prod"]: <a> elif environment in ["all"]: <b> else: c` - then in each of `a`, `b` and `c` you'd have `if account_ids: <d> else: <e>`. it's not much but i think it'd do wonders for readability at the very least

Comment: If I'm reading this code correctly, then `filter_stacks(stacks, 'noprod', [])` would match all production stacks? I agree with @RichardNeumann, this production logic is broken. It needs refactoring at a higher level.

Comment: I would say your linter is making a good suggestion, I find this code hard to follow as written.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Simplifications

- `re.compile("(nonprod|non-prod)")` is just a complicated way to write a badly performing regex for `re.compile("non-?prod")`, which does the same, but better.
- extract `re.compile("all")` into a variable like you did with `non_prod_regex`, or better yet, do a string comparison: `if environment == "all"`... Achieves the same effect, but is quicker (because no regex involved).

#### A different design

An alterative to having that for-loop inside of the if-statements would be to have the if-statements inside of your loop. That can be made much cleaner by converting it to a list comprehension:

```py
    is_nonprod = bool(non_prod_regex.match(environment))
    has_accounts = bool(account_ids)

    stacks_to_update = [stack for stack in stacks if (
      (environment == "all" or (is_nonprod == bool(non_prod_regex.match(stack["StackName"]))))
      and (not has_accounts or stack["AccountId"] in account_ids)
    )]
```

This design makes an interesting simplification: You have two dimensions of things you want to check: The environment of the stack and the account of the stack. Both of these dimensions impact the result set, but are independent of one another.

This allows us to simplify things a bit by noticing the repeating pattern:

- if there are `account_ids`, the account needs to be checked, otherwise we don't care
- The environment must either be "all" or the 'nonprod-status' of the stack must match the environment.

These two conditions must be fulfilled to include a stack in the result set.
The first one is easier, it's just an implication \$A \Rightarrow s.aid \in A\$, which is equivalent to \$\neg A \lor s.aid \in A\$ (`not account_ids or ...`)

The second condition is equally simple to implement and combining the two conditions with `and` gets all the results filtered the way we need them to.

Comment: re: the regex... i doubt it makes a difference honestly, since unless the engine in question is bad the regex probably gets compiled to an nfa/dfa. so the decision is to choose whichever one is more maintainable... and that really depends on the user.

Comment: well actually, even better: `if environment in ["nonprod", "non-prod"]: <a> elif environment in ["all"]: <b> else: c`

Comment: @somebody except for the fact that string interning is a thing, the compilation of a regex takes time and even if it is a DFA, following a pointered graph instead of comparing elements of an array is slower. Note that the if you are suggesting won't work well in a list comprehension and is IMO easier expressed using the `XOR` semantic

Comment: "following a pointered graph"??? what exactly is that referring to? also imo the list comprehension doesn't look great... plus i wasn't replying to that section at all.

Answer (score 4):

**A data-oriented function should return data or raise an exception, not
print**. If there are no matching stacks, just return an empty list or raise.

**Establish a habit of defining regular expressions with raw strings**. If you always define regex patterns with raw strings,
you never have to waste time thinking about whether your pattern
contains things like `\n`, `\t`, and so forth. This is one example
of a preemptive strategy to avoid silly bugs. Efficient developers have
many habits like this.

**Instead of checking everything at once, apply multiple filtering passes**.
Your current strategy sets up all of the conditional logic branches based on
the environment and the presence/absence of `account_ids` and then writes the
complete loop for each branch. That's a lot of code and it imposes a high
mental cost on the reader who must try to discern small differences between
each branch. But that's not necessary. If you break the process down into
phases, everything simplifies: first filter by environment, and then filter by
account IDs. Notice also that this reorganization of the code
has the benefit of laying the groundwork should you decide
in the future to put environment-filtering and account-id-filtering
in separate functions (for example, if the filtering logic in
one or both becomes more complex).

**Organize code in commented paragraphs**. As illustrated below,
a few simple comments -- especially if they focus on strategy or
purpose -- can help future readers navigate the code. The most likely
future reader is you.

```
import re

def filter_stacks(stacks, environment, account_ids):
    # Determine whether the environment is nonprod.
    nonprod_rgx = re.compile(r'non-?prod')
    env_is_nonprod = bool(nonprod_rgx.match(environment))

    # Filter based on environment.
    if re.compile(r'all').match(environment):
        to_update = stacks
    else:
        to_update = [
            s
            for s in stacks
            if env_is_nonprod is bool(nonprod_rgx.search(s['StackName']))
        ]

    # Optionally filter based on account_ids.
    if account_ids:
        return [s for s in to_update if s['AccountId'] in account_ids]
    else:
        return to_update
```

Answer (score 3):

According to your code the first optimization that came to my mind is to group your if statements by the variable accounts_ids like the next example

```
    if accounts_ids:
        if non_prod_regex.match(environment):
            do....
        elif re.compile("all").match(environment):
            do....
        else:
            do...
    else:
        if non_prod_regex.match(environment):
            do....
        elif re.compile("all").match(environment):
            stacks_to_update = stacks
        else:
            do....
```

That will make the code a bit more readable, however when there is multiple if statements my recommendation is that you use a Visitor pattern to solve the problem. Hope it helps to clarify

Answer (score 3):

As other answers already pointed out, you should not compile call `re.compile` several times, and there is no need to try to filter according to all filters at the same time.

I would go even further and suggest to use iterators, which are great tools in Python. It would allow you to write a single function per filter, and apply a bunch of function to each stack in a single iteration.

I would also suggest to type your code, which makes any review process easier.

Here is a suggestion that will work only in python 3.8+ (due to `functools.cached_property` usage):

```py
import re
from functools import cached_property
from typing import (
    Any,
    Iterable,
    Iterator,
    List,
    Pattern,
    TypeVar,
    Mapping,
)


class Patterns:
    """Wrapper regex patterns into cached properties"""

    @cached_property
    def NON_PROD(self) -> Pattern[str]:
        return re.compile(r"non-?prod")

    @cached_property
    def ALL(self) -> Pattern[str]:
        return re.compile(r"all")


# Create a global instance that can be used accross the module
PATTERNS = Patterns()


def account_ids_filter(stack: Mapping[str, Any], account_ids: List[str]) -> bool:
    """Return True is stack account ID is present in list of accoutn IDs"""
    return stack["AccountId"] in account_ids


def environment_filter(stack: Mapping[str, Any], environment: str) -> bool:
    """Return True if stack matches environment else False"""
    env_is_non_prod = True if PATTERNS.NON_PROD.match(environment) else False
    return env_is_non_prod is bool(PATTERNS.NON_PROD.search(stack["StackName"]))


# Whatever type is going into filter_stacks will also come out from filter_stacks
StackT = TypeVar("StackT", bound=Mapping[str, Any])

def filter_stacks(
    stacks: Iterable[StackT],
    environment: str,
    account_ids: List[str],
) -> Iterator[StackT]:
    """Returns an iterator of filtered stacks"""
    # Return early in case "all" pattern matches
    if PATTERNS.ALL.match(environment):
        return iter(stacks)

    # Iterate through stacks
    for stack in stacks:
        # Filter using environment
        if not environment_filter(stack, environment):
            continue
        # Filter using account IDs
        if not account_ids_filter(stack, account_ids):
            continue
        yield stack


def get_filtered_stacks(
    stacks: Iterable[StackT], environment: str, account_ids: List[str]
) -> List[StackT]:
    """Returns a list of filtered stacks"""
    return list(filter_stacks(stacks, environment=environment, account_ids=account_ids))
```

Because we're working with iterators, the input `stacks` argument is iterated on once only.

Moreover, regexp patterns are stored as cached properties on a global variable so that they are generated lazily (on first call, and not at module import)

If you filters grow more complex, you can write more filter functions, unit test them easily, and call them in the `filter_stacks` function

Comment: Your account_ids_filter function could be simplified. `return True if x else False` is equivalent to `return x` (assuming x is a boolean, which it is here).

Comment: [`Pattern.match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.match) returns either `None` if there is no match, or an instance of `re.Match`. So it's definitely not a boolean. I could have done `bool(...)`  instead of `True if ... else False`, but I guess it's a matter of style ?

Comment: I’m talking about `stack[“AccountId”] in account_ids` which is a Boolean

Comment: You're right, my bad ! I fixed it